# Excel - simple scatter of linear curve appears non-linear in chart: axis scaling error?

Tags: excel, scatter

My super simple linear curve for some reason ends up not being straight in Excel scatter. Each Y value is X times 182:

```
0.0, 0.0    
0.001777, 0.323414    
0.044748, 8.144136    
498.75, 90772.5
```

When zooming in on the 3rd point (setting x-axis max = 0.1, y-axis max = 20), the curve is no longer straight. Linear trend of 182X is far off ....
[Excel view straight line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpn4n.jpg)

Changing the x-axis max again to 1.0 makes the curve change it shape to the opposite site: [Changed x-axis max to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXF5U.jpg)

Tested on both Office 2013 and 2016 Versions of 64-bit 365, other PCs etc.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yea... That's fun. The linear regression equation is correct, but the plot of it is bonkers. :/

Comment: Could it be some sort of numerical error in the chart due to the large numerical difference between the smallest and largest data point?

Comment: I was reading that there can appear to be issues related to trend line plotting due to rounding based on decimals in the axis. I tried changing the number format of the regression formula, x-axis, and y-axis but was still hitting the way-off trend plot. The plot gets more accurate, the more you shrink that last number, so I agree. It's probably guessing at the slope when it plots based on some average level of sig-fig on the incoming data and getting way off mark.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My main concern is still for the plotted series and not the trend line, it's just for additional illustration. The main plot is also off, should definitely be straight which is not the case as seen in my links. The line is simply y=182x ...

Comment: Well.. it's right for the dots that are plotted, but it's like when Excel has to guess at the slope to hit that number that is 4 orders of magnitude higher, it guesses wrong for both the trend and the last connected line. Really it doesn't make much sense to plot that thing since it has no relationship to the other numbers, and if there is a relationship that needs to be shown, perhaps a logarithmic y-axis is in order.